# Why local changes would be overwritten by merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have next local changes:

```
diff --git a/lib/Art.pm b/lib/Art.pm
index c8fd249..4bd479f 100644
--- a/lib/Art.pm
+++ b/lib/Art.pm
@@ -61,6 +61,7 @@ sub startup {


     $self->hook( around_action  =>  \&Art::Controller::_log_request        );
+    $self->hook( around_action  =>  \&Art::Controller::_store_referral     );
     $self->hook( around_action  =>  \&Art::Controller::_json_as_urlencoded );
     $self->hook( after_dispatch =>  \&Art::Controller::_mail_exception     );
     # NOTICE: before_render is called even before rendering included template
```

And has next changes in the stash:

```
diff --git a/lib/Art.pm b/lib/Art.pm
index 0dde0ec..cff11c9 100644
--- a/lib/Art.pm
+++ b/lib/Art.pm
@@ -32,6 +32,7 @@ sub startup {
     push @{ $self->plugins->namespaces }, __PACKAGE__ .'::Plugin';
     $self->plugin( Config =>  { file => 'conf/' .$self->moniker .'.conf' } );
     $self->plugin( 'TagHelpers::FetchPanel' );
+    $self->plugin( 'UserReferral',  key => 'r' );

     # default_page is used in redirections. Redirect to site root by default
```

**As you can see these changes are not overlap.**

Why I get this error when try to apply this stash?

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    lib/Art.pm
```

Is there a way to apply this patch without this error?

Comment: A Git stash contains *two* (or sometimes three) commits and `git stash show` shows only differences computed through one of these two commits, specifically the work-tree commit. It seems likely that the conflict occurs through the other (index) commit. This would occur if you apply the stash with `--index`, which uses `git read-tree` rather than `git read-tree --reset`. If so, simply omitting `--index` so that Git *discards* the conflicting saved index should do it.

Comment: @torek I suspected there would be an alternative to the answer I gave, and you actually came to mind.  In practice, I probably wouldn't get as deep as worrying about which stash commit was the culprit.  Would my answer go wrong in any case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Making a commit will usually allow you to apply the stash even with `--index`. You *can* still get merge conflicts, although in this case I don't expect there would be any; and if the merge conflicts are severe, you might have to use `git stash branch` or equivalent to apply while still preserving the separate index and work-tree. Bottom line is that *with* `--index`, even making a new commit isn't *guaranteed* to suffice, but it will *usually* work. Applying *without* `--index` is easier, in a fundamental sense, as it gives Git permission to discard most of the index commit.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to apply this patch without this error?

You are getting this error because, as the error message says, you have local changes to the file `lib/Art.pm` which would be overwritten by the merge.  So, the first thing you should do is commit your local changes via:

```
git add lib/Art.pm
# and commit any other work you want
git commit -m 'local changes to Art.pm'
```

After this, you can apply the stash via:

```
git stash apply
```

Note that you still may get merge conflicts here.  If you do, it just means that Git was being cautious and did not want to assume which final version of `Art.pm` it should use.  In the event of conflicts, this file would be peppered with conflict markers looking like `<<<<` and `====`.  Resolve the conflicts, and make another commit to finish applying the stash.

Comment: Ah, sure. But if I remember right it is sufficient to just add file into index without committing it

Comment: But then how would this work out?  You would have a working version from the stash, and a staged version from somewhere else.  How would you resolve this?

Comment: In this case no merge conflicts. Changes are just applied to wc and finish. Stashed changes leaved intact

Comment: There are multiple ways we could have dealt with this, but this is probably my first choice.  You can always squash the two commits together by committing via `git commit --amend` to make a single commit.